# Where is the documentation for core associative arrays?

Tags: 7, entities, hooks

I have been using Drupal for a few months now at work. I love the developer documentation, but I have to say, I feel like its incomplete -- either that, or I just don't know where to find the other half.

I see documentation for functions and hooks everywhere, but I don't see any documentation for the format of core data structures.

Example one: [this page from the official docs](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!wysiwyg!wysiwyg.api.php/function/hook_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter/7) has extensive explanation on `hook_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter`, but it gives no complete disclosure what the `$settings` parameter can contain.

Example two: [this page from the official docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/render-arrays/render-arrays-overview) has great explanation of the concept of "Render Arrays" and the functionality thereof, but has no description of the format of the associative array passed to the `render()` function, causing me to `var_dump($user_page)` for hours and come up with monstrosities like: `<?php echo $user_page["system_main"]["nodes"][$first_key]["field_objective"]["#object"]->field_targets["und"][0]["safe_value"]; ?>` on my custom .tpl.php files.

Is this information in the code itself, or somewhere else?

Comment: Why echo out values from a render array instead of `print render($content['field_name']);`?

Comment: @Kevin Where does it tell me how to do that in the official docs?

Comment: Hooks tend to be documented in MODULE.api.php, often with usage examples. Render arrays can't be documented in the way I think you're looking for as they're loosely formed. Anything with `#` starting the key is a "property", and provides meta data to whatever function ends up rendering the content, and anything without a `#` starting the key is itself another render array and rendered recursively

Comment: For your example: "system_main" is a region, "nodes" is something the page callback for that request has returned as part of a render array, "field_objective" is a field on the node, "#object" is metadata, the object itself which will be used by the rendering function, "field_targets" is a property on that object containing the values. It's quite hard to document that in any meaningful way as it's product of the dynamic system rather than a single predefined process. Once you're comfortable with how render arrays work generically, it'll probably make more sense

Comment: *drupalcontrib.org* is not the official documentation. use *[api.drupal.org](https://api.drupal.org)* and *[drupal.org/docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8)*

Comment: Yes we really need to fix that... drupalcontrib is way out of date especially for Drupal 8. It's confusing people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Render arrays are defined (in Drupal 7) with the [hook_element_info](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_element_info/7.x) hook.

To see what attributes a render element can accept you can check the MODULE_element_info function that defined it.

For example looking at [system_element_info](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_element_info/7.x) we can see that the `page` render element accepts a `#show_messages` attribute and that it contains a boolean value.

For more information you can also look for the template_preprocess_ELEMENT function for the element.

[template_preprocess_page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7.x) in our example.